# Generate Maven archetype from Java code

Tags: java, maven, catalog, maven-archetype

I want to know if it's possible to run the maven command: archetype:generate in Java code.
I've tried this with the maven embedder, but this library is deprecated.

I want to do an archetype:generate from a remote catalog, and capture the required properties of the archetype.

The maven command I want to run is for example:

```
mvn archetype:generate \
    -DgroupId=com.maven \
    -DartifactId=test \
    -DarchetypeVersion=1.0-alpha-4 \
    -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes \
    -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-j2ee-simple \
    -DinteractiveMode=false \
    -DarchetypeCatalog=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml
```

for some archetypes there are required properties, after you do this request.
I want to display these properties on a GUI screen, just like the m2eclipse plugin does, so the user can fill in these properties.

Does anybody has a suggestion?

Answer (score 4):

You could try to use the [Maven Invoker](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-invoker/).

Add this dependency to the `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.shared</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-invoker</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

And here is what the code might look like:

```
import org.apache.maven.shared.invoker.*;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Properties;

public class MavenInvoker {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MavenInvocationException {
        InvocationRequest request = new DefaultInvocationRequest();
        request.setGoals( Collections.singletonList("archetype:generate") );
        request.setInteractive(false);
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("groupId", "com.maven");
        properties.setProperty("artifactId", "test");
        properties.setProperty("archetypeVersion", "1.0-alpha-4");
        properties.setProperty("archetypeGroupId", "org.apache.maven.archetypes");
        properties.setProperty("archetypeArtifactId", "maven-archetype-j2ee-simple");
        properties.setProperty("archetypeCatalog", "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml");
        request.setProperties(properties);
        Invoker invoker = new DefaultInvoker();
        InvocationResult result = invoker.execute( request );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If all else fails, you can use [Runtime.exec()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html).

Comment: I don't want to be dependent of a Maven installation. With the maven embedder, i don't have to install Maven on the machine, that's what i want.