# how to interact with system cmd line using java code

Tags: java, maven, apache-nifi, java-io, maven-archetype

I'm trying to create a Java code that creates a nifi customized processor ! so in order to do that I need to use windows **cmd windows** and launch `mvn archetype:generate` then choose the modele nifi by typing `nifi` then choose the project by typing`1` the I need to write the groupeId, the artifact ...

[image]
[image]
[image]

I need to do all that automatically by using a java code : I tryed this code :

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class CmdTest {
    public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException {
        String line;
        OutputStream stdin = null;
        InputStream stderr = null;
        InputStream stdout = null;

          // launch EXE and grab stdin/stdout and stderr
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(
                "cmd.exe", "/c", "cd \"C:\\users\\eya\\desktop\\javaprocessor\" && mvn archetype:generate");
            builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
            Process process = builder.start();
          stdin = process.getOutputStream ();
          stderr = process.getErrorStream ();
          stdout = process.getInputStream ();

          // "write" the parms into stdin
          line = "nifi" + "\n";
          stdin.write(line.getBytes() );
          stdin.flush();

          line = "1" + "\n";
          stdin.write(line.getBytes() );
          stdin.flush();

          line = "33" + "\n";
          stdin.write(line.getBytes() );
          stdin.flush();

          line = "javaproceSSor" + "\n";
          stdin.write(line.getBytes() );
          stdin.flush();

          line = "javaprocessor" + "\n";
          stdin.write(line.getBytes() );
          stdin.flush();

          line = "" + "\n";
          stdin.write(line.getBytes() );
          stdin.flush();

          line = "javapro" + "\n";
          stdin.write(line.getBytes() );
          stdin.flush();

          line = "" + "\n";
          stdin.write(line.getBytes() );
          stdin.flush();

          line = "y" + "\n";
          stdin.write(line.getBytes() );
          stdin.flush();

          stdin.close();

          // clean up if any output in stdout
          BufferedReader brCleanUp =
            new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (stdout));
          while ((line = brCleanUp.readLine ()) != null) {

              System.out.println ("[Stdout] " + line);
          }
          brCleanUp.close();

          // clean up if any output in stderr
          brCleanUp =
            new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (stderr));
          while ((line = brCleanUp.readLine ()) != null) {
            System.out.println ("[Stderr] " + line);
          }
          brCleanUp.close();
    }
}
```

but it only read "nifi" the others no ! and here is the result :

```
    [Stdout] 2679: remote -> us.fatehi:schemacrawler-archetype-plugin-command (-)
[Stdout] 2680: remote -> us.fatehi:schemacrawler-archetype-plugin-dbconnector (-)
[Stdout] 2681: remote -> us.fatehi:schemacrawler-archetype-plugin-lint (-)
[Stdout] 2682: remote -> ws.osiris:osiris-archetype (Maven Archetype for Osiris)
[Stdout] 2683: remote -> xyz.luan.generator:xyz-gae-generator (-)
[Stdout] 2684: remote -> xyz.luan.generator:xyz-generator (-)
[Stdout] 2685: remote -> za.co.absa.hyperdrive:component-archetype (-)
[Stdout] Choose a number or apply filter (format: [groupId:]artifactId, case sensitive contains): 1589: Choose org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart version: 
[Stdout] 1: 1.0-alpha-1
[Stdout] 2: 1.0-alpha-2
[Stdout] 3: 1.0-alpha-3
[Stdout] 4: 1.0-alpha-4
[Stdout] 5: 1.0
[Stdout] 6: 1.1
[Stdout] 7: 1.3
[Stdout] 8: 1.4
[Stdout] Choose a number: 8: Define value for property 'groupId': [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[Stdout] [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[Stdout] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[Stdout] [INFO] Total time:  12.592 s
[Stdout] [INFO] Finished at: 2020-04-12T21:13:20+01:00
[Stdout] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[Stdout] [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.1.2:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: null: MojoFailureException: NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
[Stdout] [ERROR] 
[Stdout] [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[Stdout] [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[Stdout] [ERROR] 
[Stdout] [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Stdout] [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

if there is any way to generate mvn projects automatically then you are very welcome to help

> EDIT: 
>   I tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16541124/generate-maven-archetype-from-java-code) but I didn't know how to configure it

Comment: Why are you using Java for this? There are more suitable languages for this kind of scripting.

Comment: @m0skit0 because this is involved in a bigger project and the first step is to generat processors automatically ! and to do that I need to interact with cmd windows using java

Comment: Even if it's part of a bigger project you don't have to use Java for everything... It's like using a hammer to lay butter on a toast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just don't do that. The mvn command could accept all required arguments in command line so there are no interactive actions required. See the documentation on the plugin and supply parameters accordingly into single command. See http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/generate-mojo.html
There is an example here: [Specify archetype for archetype:generate on command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909455/specify-archetype-for-archetypegenerate-on-command-line)

Comment: Ifound this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16541124/generate-maven-archetype-from-java-code)  but it does not give me the hand to choose the right filter **nifi**  or my prefered archetype

Comment: Sorry but I did not get your solution :( !

Comment: @maryemneyli You don't have the search feature, instead you put in the right groupId, artifactId and version as parameter. But what is the advantage of first putting "nifi" and then "1" instead of directly using `org.apache.nifi:nifi-processor-bundle-archetype`?

Comment: @JFMeier when I enter this command `>mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-app -DarchetypeArtifactId=org.apache.nifi:nifi-processor-bundle-archetype -DinteractiveMode=false` an error appear : [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.1.2:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: The desired archetype does not exist (org.apache.maven.archetypes:org.apache.nifi:nifi-processor-bundle-archetype:1.0) -> [Help 1]

Comment: You must specify `archetypeArtifactId`, `archetypeGroupId` and `archetypeVersion` separately: http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/generate-mojo.html

Comment: `mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=remote -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.nifi -DarchetypeArtifactId=nifi-processor-bundle-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=1.9.2 -DgroupId=test -DartifactId=test -DartifactBaseName=test -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackage=test.package.test` is working just fine @JFMeier can you please make it as an answer

Comment: @maryemneyli Just accept this one. My comments were just clarifications.